# can dmidecode display GPU information?

Tags: linux

I write a small script to extract the hardware information of computers.
Because the computer are small and only for test purposes i don't want to install to much on them. If it is not possible i would just go e.g. with hwinfo.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: what kind of "GPU information" are you looking for? This is a bit vague...

Comment: I need the vendor and model information

Comment: is what lspci gives you (or, what you find without lspci in /sys/) good enough?

Comment: lspci is unfortunately not on the test pcs. Where can i find the GPU information in /sys/ ?

Comment: You can find that out easily by running `strace -o /tmp/log.strace lspci` on a machine with a card and `lspci` installed (by the way, lspci is *really* not large...), and then look for `/sys/` in the /tmp/log.strace file.

Comment: Okay thank you! I'll try it.

Comment: the nice thing is, you can just extract `vendor`, `device` and `class` information numerically from the /sys/ entries, and then collect these few bytes. The big table that maps these numerical values to names can be on a central computer that evaluates the collected data, and doesn't need to reside on all the "small" computers.